# Instantiate multiple twitter accounts with Ruby on Rails twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

I am using sferiks gem https://github.com/sferik/twitter

I want to instantiate multiple accounts from within a loop.

This is what I thought would work...

```
twitter_accounts.each do |twitter_account|
    username = twitter_account['username']
    token = twitter_account['oauth_token']
    secret = twitter_account['oauth_token_secret']

    username = Twitter::Client.new(
        :oauth_token => token,
        :oauth_token_secret => secret
    )
end
```

If I was to instantiate multiple accounts without a loop

```
erik = Twitter::Client.new(
  :oauth_token => "Erik's access token",
  :oauth_token_secret => "Erik's access secret"
)

john = Twitter::Client.new(
  :oauth_token => "John's access token",
  :oauth_token_secret => "John's access secret"
)
```

then to post using the gem you would do

```
Thread.new{erik.update("test")}
Thread.new{john.update("test")}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the usage of the `username` variable just an error in your post? If not, you are overwriting your twitter client instantiation for every account and `username` will only contain the last one. Use a hash to store them one by one.

```
accounts = {}
twitter_accounts.each do |twitter_account|
    username = twitter_account['username']
    token = twitter_account['oauth_token']
    secret = twitter_account['oauth_token_secret']

    accounts[username] = Twitter::Client.new(
        :oauth_token => token,
        :oauth_token_secret => secret
    )
end

Thread.new{accounts['erik'].update('test')} # post stuff
```

Comment: ah okay! This is how you would use the gem. Thread.new{maxrosecollins.update("test tweet")} Does the above answer set maxrosecollins = Twitter::Client.new(etc)

Comment: err no it doesn't. I think now I get what you were trying to do. You wanted a variable named after your Twitter usernames. Instead you filled the variable username with the value of the name (`username = 'maxrosecollins'`. To get the connection to the name, see my edit.

Comment: I updated my question to show how you do it without a loop. I hope that makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: Yeah that's why I modified it in my solution to using a hash, using the usernames as keys. You can then access them as `accounts['erik']`. I'd advise against naming variables dynamically after strings because actually getting this to work will be confusing (using meta programming). Even then you will have an unmanageable mess of arbitrary variables. Use the hash to group them into one for easier access.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. How would you suggest I do it instead? At the moment when they connect their twitter account to my app it saves their twitter handle and that is what I was going to use as the dynamic variable?

Comment: That depends heavily on what you actually want to to with it and how your models are built. Using the information I've got, I cannot give you any more advice than I've given in my answer. So instead of directly using the variable `erik` to do something with it, just change it to `accounts['erik']` and you're good to go. My updated code example already includes this. I cannot really comment on how to use the twitter gem or threading since I'm not too experienced with these in the Ruby realm.

Comment: Okay no worries. Cheers for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome. I think next time we should switch to chat in order to discuss the specifics of your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Using `each`, the code overwrite `username` and finally you get the last `Twitter::Client` object and the return value of the block is not saved.

Use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) instead.

```
accounts = twitter_accounts.map do |twitter_account|
    username = twitter_account['username']
    token = twitter_account['oauth_token']
    secret = twitter_account['oauth_token_secret']

    Twitter::Client.new(
        :oauth_token => token,
        :oauth_token_secret => secret
    )
end
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense! I have edited the question to show how you would instantiate without a loop. The username needs to = Twitter::Client.new()